# Catching user-defined Oracle exceptions in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I have a stored procedure in Oracle that throws a user-defined error using RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR in certain situations. The user-defined error code is -20000.

I am calling the stored procedure from an ASP.NET application using VB.NET, and I would like to catch this specific error and display a custom error message, however VB.NET is catching the error number as 20000, not -20000.

Is there a different way to catch this error or a better way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research, I think the 20000 error code is what I need to catch. According to the link below, ORA-20000 is for exceptions generated by RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR, so I think I'm safe just catching 20000 as opposed to -20000. This was confusing to me.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/toc.htm

Comment: In my case, RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR is getting raised by oracle pl\sql code, but somehow in vb.net code, it is not going into CATCH block. Could you please tell me where is the problem or how it was coming in your case.